# Disable organisation name masking azure devops

Tags: azure-devops

When I use the organisation name in a variable, the name will be masked in the log and parameters.
Can I disable this or where can I find the setting?

When I use this in inline PowerShell variable I get the error *** is not recognized.

The variable is not secret.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The organisation name also exist in a variable group and was not used.
I removed the variable and the problem was fixed.

Comment: How did you remove that variable?